# Adding Paging functionality to asp net core 1.0 web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use ReflectionIT to add paging to my application 
but when i run the app and access the action which has the paging functionality i
get the following error

[image]

Comment: Your stack trace is really clear: the `sortExpression` you provided doesn't exist on that type, and that results in `MemberInfo` being `null`.

Comment: no i have provided a fixed value for sort expression ,its not about that

Comment: "its not about that" Yes it is, your stack trace and you exception are telling your that, you provided an invalid `sortExpression`.

Comment: thank you so much i was not concentrating well , it worked